# why doesn't my db.autosave function work discord.py?

Tags: python, database, discord.py

There is a part in my code that just doesn't work for me. Does anybody know any good solution for this?

```
from discord import Embed, File
from discord import Intents
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as BotBase
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound
import db
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

PREFIX = "+"
OWNER_IDS = [436163963894366209]

class Bot(BotBase):
  def __init__(self):
    self.PREFIX = PREFIX
    self.ready = False
    self.guild = None
    self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    db.autosave(self.scheduler)
    
    super().__init__(
      command_prefix = PREFIX, 
      owner_ids = OWNER_IDS,
      itnets = Intents.all()
    )
```

Console output:

```
File "c:\Users\cuz i can\Downloads\DiscordBottie\lib\bot\__init__.py", line 21, in __init__
    db.autosave(self.scheduler)
AttributeError: module 'db' has no attribute 'autosave'
```

Comment: What documentation/tutorial are you using that says `db.autosave` exists?

Comment: Hi @TheFungusAmongUs ! I'm using this tutorial for the bot I'm building! 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le_RNN4po30

Comment: Did you download the requirements in the description? It looks like something separate from the `db`  module and instead is code you have to download and put in the same directory.